# I am unable to test SharedPreference using Mockito

Tags: android, testing, mockito, preferences

I am unable to mock sharedPreference and when i test my presenter then sharepreference instance is null.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class PreferencesPresenterTest {

    @Mock
    PreferencesMvpView preferencesMvpView;

    @Mock
    ApiService apiService;

    @Mock
    Context context;

    @Mock
    SchedulerProvider mSchedulerProvider;

    PreferencesPresenter mPresenter;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
        mPresenter = new PreferencesPresenter(compositeDisposable, apiService, mSchedulerProvider);


        // mPrefences = new AppPreferences();
        mPresenter.onAttach(preferencesMvpView);

    }

    @Test
    public void testFilter() throws Exception {
        Mockito.when(mSchedulerProvider.getUiScheduler()).thenReturn(Schedulers.trampoline());
        Mockito.when(mSchedulerProvider.getWorkerScheduler()).thenReturn(Schedulers.trampoline());


        mPresenter.loadPreferenceData();
    }


}
```

//This is the method which i am testing

```
@Override
    public void loadPreferenceData() {

        long userId = mPreferences.getLong(AppPreferences.USER_ID);
        getMvpView().showLoading();

        getCompositeDisposable().add(getApiService().getPreferencesData(userId)
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().getWorkerScheduler())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().getUiScheduler())
                .subscribe(
                        jsonObject -> {
                            //Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "PreferencesPresenter : loadPreferenceData: onSuccess");
                            if (!isViewAttached()) {
                                return;
                            }

                            getMvpView().hideLoading();
                            if (jsonObject != null && AppUtils.containsValue(jsonObject, JsonKeys.DATA))
                                setupFieldList(new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.get(JsonKeys.DATA), Preferences.class));
                        }
                        , throwable -> {
                            // Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "PreferencesPresenter : loadPreferenceData: Error");
                            if (!isViewAttached()) {
                                return;
                            }

                            getMvpView().hideLoading();
                            handleApiError(throwable);
                        }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running unit tests? By default, any calls to the Android framework from within a unit test will throw an exception.

From https://developer.android.com/training/testing/fundamentals#interact-android-environment:

> You can control and verify the elements of the Android framework with which your app interacts by running unit tests against a modified version of android.jar, which doesn't contain any code. Because your app's calls to the Android framework throw exceptions by default, you need to stub out every one of these interactions by using a mocking framework, such as Mockito.

You have a few options here:

1. Encapsulate the code that interacts with `SharedPreferences` in a separate class and mock out that class with Mockito when testing your Presenter
2. Use [Robolectric](http://robolectric.org/), which provides an implementation of the Android SDK
3. Run instrumented tests (`androidTest`) instead of unit tests (`test`)

I would recommend #1, as that approach allows you to continue running fast JUnit tests without having to deal with the overhead of Robolectric.